# Having trouble determining the return value in assembly language

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am new to the world of assembly language/code. I find it difficult to understand but I try my best. I'm just having trouble with some of the questions I need to answer for an assignment.

2. I need to find out the return value of a specific program, if I pass echo $? as a command in the terminal, I get 10 as an answer. However my teacher's answer sheet says the answer is 9.
3. I need to find out the return value of the main (of the same program) by examining a dump of the assembler code. Again, I think the answer is 10, because 0xa = 10. However, the answer sheet again says the answer is 9. Do I need to subtract a 1 from the return value by default or something? If so, why?

   ```
   0x000000000000069f <+0>:     55               push    %rbp
   0x00000000000006a0 <+1>:     48 89 e5         mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000000006a3 <+4>:     bf 05 00 00 00   mov    $0x5,%edi
   0x00000000000006a8 <+9>:     e8 9d ff ff ff   callq  0x64a <okfisbup>
   0x00000000000006ad <+14>:    b8 0a 00 00 00   mov    $0xa,%eax
   0x00000000000006b2 <+19>:    5d               pop   %rbp
   0x00000000000006b3 <+20>:    c3               retq
   ```

When I run the program, by using ./(filename), this is what I get.

```
 iteratie: 1, buffer address  : 0x7ffe4052d0e0
 iteratie: 2, buffer address  : 0x7ffe4052d1c0
 iteratie: 3, buffer address  : 0x7ffe4052d2a0
 iteratie: 4, buffer address  : 0x7ffe4052d380
 iteratie: 5, buffer address  : 0x7ffe4052d460
```

And this is the dump of okfisbup:

```
   0x000000000000064a <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000064b <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000064e <+4>:     sub    $0xd0,%rsp
   0x0000000000000655 <+11>:    mov    %edi,%eax
   0x0000000000000657 <+13>:    mov    %al,-0xc4(%rbp)
   0x000000000000065d <+19>:    movzbl -0xc4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000664 <+26>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000000667 <+29>:    mov    %al,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x000000000000066a <+32>:    cmpb   $0x0,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x000000000000066e <+36>:    je     0x67b <okfisbup+49>
   0x0000000000000670 <+38>:    movzbl -0x1(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000674 <+42>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x0000000000000676 <+44>:    callq  0x64a <okfisbup>
   0x000000000000067b <+49>:    movzbl -0xc4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000682 <+56>:    lea    -0xc0(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000000689 <+63>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x000000000000068b <+65>:    lea    0xb6(%rip),%rdi        # 0x748
   0x0000000000000692 <+72>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000000697 <+77>:    callq  0x520 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000000069c <+82>:    nop
   0x000000000000069d <+83>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000000069e <+84>:    retq
```

Comment: From your prose I think you are right. We have yet to see the assembly, though. -- Let your teacher explain why it should be 9.

Comment: If it is 10 then it has to be 10. Nothing is added or substracted

Comment: The output should be 10. Your teacher/tutor or whatever should explain you why she/he thinks the output is 9. It's her/his job. OTOH we don't know what `okfisbup`  is.... Is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: Maybe you should also tell us the verbatim (more or less) text of the assignment.

Comment: Terminology: `echo $?` shows you the "exit status" of the last command.  Programs have exit status, which comes from either an arg to an `_exit()` system call,  or abnormal termination due to a signal.  Returning from `main` does lead to main's return value being passed to an exit syscall, so that return value becomes the exit status.  (Or at least the low 8 bits of it do.)

Comment: Thank you for posting the dump of `okfisbup`. This function seems to do some recursive stuff printing some buffer address which seems unrelated to the actual question. It does definitely not call `exit(9)`. You need to ask your teacher. From all we can see your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    movq $0xa, %eax
    popq rbp
    retq
```

The return value is `10`. The answer sheet is wrong.

The hypothesis that there's a hidden call to exit is unfair without the code given, and testing with $? revealed 10. That's enough.

EDIT: Disassembly of `okfisbup` has now been posted. It only calls iself and `printf`.

Comment: I edited my question, added the disas dump of okfisbup. I hope it helps. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I was wondering about `okfisbup` playing funny games, like messing with its return address to jump over the `mov $0xa, %eax`, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that.  Just a very boring and unoptimized function that recurses while printing the address of an otherwise unused local array.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is 10 and it your teacher is wrong

https://godbolt.org/z/8YsnvPahM

```
int main(void)
{
    return 10;
}

main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $10, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```